# Почему не изменяется Render?

Tags: reactjs

Суть простая, нажимаем на checbox, оно добавляет в массив надпись bmw, отжимаем chekbox оно эту надпись удаляет

```js
import React from "react";
import Model from "./model";


class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state = {
     WeatherObj:null,
     mark:[],
     stylecontainerinput:{
      display:"flex",
      flexDirection:"column"
     },
     stylelabel:{
      font: "15px Arial"
     },
     header:{
      font: "15px Arial"
     }
   }
  }
 
 change(e){
 let unit = e.target.value;
 let arr = this.state.mark;
  if(e.currentTarget.checked === true){
   arr.push(unit);
   this.setState=({mark: arr});
  }else{
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf(unit), 1);
   this.setState=({mark: arr});
  }
 
 }

 
 render() {
  let result;
       if(this.state.mark.length === 0){
        result= <p>Привет</p>
       }else{
        result=<p>{this.state.mark[0]}</p>
       }
        
       return(
       <div style={this.state.stylecontainerinput}>
       <p style={this.state.header}>Выбрать марку</p>
       <div>
        <input id="bmw" value="bmw" type="checkbox" onClick={this.change.bind(this)}/>
        <label style={this.state.stylelabel} htmlFor="bmw">BMW</label>
       </div>
       <div>
        {result}
       </div>
       </div>
       
       )
    
 

 }

}
export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Почему то не работает, застревает на Привет и все тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не изменяется состояние компонента потому, что Вы не правильно привязали обработчик и также неправильно изменяете состояние.

Обработчик связывается в конструкторе, через поле. Например, так:

```
this.testMethod=this.testMethod.bind(this);
```

Альтернативный вариант, вызвать обработчик через лямбду. Например, вот так:

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => this.testMethod()}>Тест</a>
```

Что касается состояния. `SetState`, это метод, а Вы его используете как свойство.

Корректный вызов:

```
this.setState({ mark: arr });
```

После правильной привязки обработчика (привязывал через лямбду) и правильного вызова SetState всё должно заработать.

Comment: Проблема в том что изменяется

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/PJb-UjvnTx_qKiUpScrFqQ.png

Comment: Нажимаю на чекбокс оно выдает массив

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/9pkglMfSRc_oo3-XcDYEGA.png

Comment: Без правильной привязки тоже будет выдавать массив. Вопрос, только будет ли он корректно сохранён в состоянии. С учётом того, что у Вас условие `this.state.mark.length === 0`, очевидно, что массив  `mark` при обработке в рендере  пуст.

Comment: Привязал. Та же конитель

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/9LBCatkxTaSxGGqZf1pZzw.png

Comment: К стати, сразу не обратил внимание, что у Вас ещё и `SetState` вызван неправильно. Ответ я дополнил. После привязки и исправления вызова `SetState` всё должно заработать.